# Synchronizing two radio buttons (Progress 4GL, JS and HTML)

Tags: javascript, progress-4gl, webspeed

I want to synchronize the HTML field, ind_title with gender, such that when I ticked Mr radio button, the Male will automatically be checked, and when I ticked Mrs or Ms, the Female will be checked. I tried this code, but it didn't seem to work. Help please? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

This is my HTML code.

```
<label class="control-label" for="linedesc">Title:</label>
<input type="radio" name="ind_title" value="1" `if ttAssuredMst.ind_title = STRING("1") then 'checked' else ''` onclick="checkGend()">Mr.
<input type="radio" name="ind_title" value="2" `if ttAssuredMst.ind_title = STRING("2") then 'checked' else ''` onclick="checkGend()">Mrs.
<input type="radio" name="ind_title" value="3" `if ttAssuredMst.ind_title = STRING("3") then 'checked' else ''` onclick="checkGend()">Ms.

<label class="control-label" for="linedesc">Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" `if ttAssuredMst.gender = 'M' then 'checked' else ''` readonly>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" `if ttAssuredMst.gender = 'F' then 'checked' else ''` readonly>Female
```

this is my JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.masktin').mask("999-999-999-999");
          $("#client_since").mask("99/99/9999");
          $("#client_since").datepicker();
          if ($("#num_addaddress2").val()=="0") {
              $("#btninsertaddress").click();
          }


        }); 

        function checkGend() {
        if (document.getElementById('mr').checked) {
        document.getElementById('male').checked = true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('mrs').checked) {
        document.getElementById('female').checked = true;
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('female').checked = true;
        }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: adding a jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: You're using getElementById but I'm not seeing any ID attributes on your inputs. 
Example: <input type="radio" name="ind_title" value="1" id="mr"

Comment: @Aliendroid how do you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

SpeedScript is executed on the server side by the WebSpeed agent. This means you will have to submit the values of the form every time you switch among "Mr" , "Ms" and "Mrs". For your purpose, it is not required to use SpeedScript.

Javascript, which runs on client side, will do the job most efficiently.